# "What place are you going to?" or "Where are you going?"

Tags: where

If I ask the question "Where are you going?", is it okay for me to say,

> "What place are you going to?"

or

> "To what place are you going?"

instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both questions are grammatically correct.

Compare:

'Where are you going?' - 'Overseas.'

'What place are you going to?' - 'France and Germany.'

Comment: Grammatically correct but neither is very natural-sounding.